# Which BLE Beacon should I use for cross-platform app?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, cross-platform, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project, where I should use BLE Beacons for sending/recieving JSON, which one should I use?
I seek for cross-platform SDK and API. The ones I found yet are

- [Bluecats](http://bluecats.com/beacons.html) (has `phonegap`  support 25$x1)
- [Estimote](http://estimote.com/) (100$x3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on the type of programming you want to do (only basic scanning for beacons to determine the phone's location) and especially whether you want to use the "beacon handling platform" provided by the manufacturers.

The hardware beacons itself just transmits a Bluetooth signal. So as long as you're not going to use features like Esimote's [Secure UUID](https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/201371053-What-security-features-does-Estimote-offer-How-does-Secure-UUID-work-) you should be free in choosing the hardware beacon, as long as they are conform to the [iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) or [eddystone](https://github.com/google/eddystone) protocol (depending on which you want to use).

Due to these protocols, you're free in choosing the SDK you're using. Estimote or Bluecats API attach to the phone OS' Bluetooth functions and offer a more convenient API interface. The task of basic scanning for beacons could be done with [tools given by the OS](http://www.codemag.com/article/1405051), so usage of an SDK is not necessarily. For more advanced interaction the mostly proprietary SDKs by the manufacturer are required (like getting the measured temperature or accelerometer value). Same goes for configuration of the beacons which is done via apps by the manufacturers. However, there are some third-party apps capable of configuring the basic beacon information based on the protocol (e.g. uuid, major and minor in case of iBeacon).

The Google Beacons page lists some additional manufacturers which may be an alternative to the two already mentioned in you question: https://developers.google.com/beacons/

Comment: I want to send/recieve JSON, can BLE transmit such things?

Comment: Bluetooth may transmit any kind of data, but the BLE Beacons only broadcast an alphanumeric-ID on regular basis. Phones may receive these broadcasts and can then determine that they are in a given range of the transmitting beacon.